# Convert SQL native query to HQL Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have below table

Order Table

```
  OrderId   UserId    status       orderDate
       1    101       In-Progress   30/08/20
       2    101       Completed     28/08/20
       3    101       Validating    28/08/20
       4    102       In-Progress   02/09/20
       5    102       Completed     28/08/20
       6    102       In-Progress   10/09/20
       7    103       In-Progress   12/09/20
       8    103       In-Progress   15/09/20
```

I am looking for output

1. All order which is in "In-Progress" Status.
2. For same user id none of the order status is in "validating".
3. Order which is having earlier orderDate

With above condition o/p will look like this:

```
OrderId   UserId    status       orderDate
      4     102     In-Progress   02/09/20
      7     103     In-Progress   12/09/20
```

In order to achieve this I wrote below native query which I want to convert into HQL.
OR
Any simple HQL query to achieve this ?

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        UserId, MIN(orderDate) AS date
    FROM
        Order
    GROUP BY UserId) t2
        INNER JOIN
    Order t1 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId
        AND t1.orderDate = t2.date
        AND t1.UserId NOT IN (SELECT 
            UserId
        FROM
            Order
        WHERE
            status IN ('Validating'))
        AND t1.status = 'In-Progress';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM Orders o1
WHERE o1.status = 'In-Progress'
NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM Orders o2
    WHERE o2.UserId = o1.UserId
    AND o2.status = 'Validating')
AND EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
   FROM Orders o3
   WHERE o3.UserId = o1.UserId
   AND o3.orderDate > o1.orderDate)
```

With the first `NOT EXISTS`, you exclude all orders have other orders for the same user with the status 'Validating'

With the second `EXISTS`, you consider orders where exists a next order date (for the same user)

I've named Orders, the Java object, to prevent error with keyword order of `order by` clause

Comment: Thanks for your time but not working as expected I updated the same as :      




```
SELECT 
    O1.*
FROM
    orders O1
WHERE
    O1.orderDate IN (SELECT 
            MIN(orderDate)
        FROM
            Orders O2
        WHERE
            O1.userId = O2.userId
                AND O2.userId NOT IN (SELECT 
                    userId
                FROM
                    Orders
                WHERE
                    Status IN (‘Validating’)))
        AND O1.status = ‘In-progress’;
```